# How to plot earthquake data with magnitude proportional to size of the data point in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv, geospatial, latitude-longitude, scaling

I am importing different csv files, using readmatrix(), from the USGS website that includes the latitude, longitude, and magnitude of earthquakes during a certain time period.  I am uing the geoscatter command which can take vectors for lat, lon and marker size (and color scale) but the problem is that the marker size is a value with points^2 units. Magnitude is given on the richter scale (0-9 or so) which is logarithmic, so as shown in the code, I tried to convert the values back by taking the square root of 10 raised to the magnitude and rescaling but it's still not great. I dont want to have to use the rescale as a quick-fix. Im just not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, if any one is familiar with geoscatter I would also like to explore the idea of the user being able to limit the view to only one continent or country, as well as possibly creating a time lapse of the earthquakes because the time data is included in the csv.

Here is the website with the data I'm using: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/csv.php

Here is the code I have so far:
(I am using a live script and have utilized a drop down box to switch between time frames, so only the data for the past month is used to simply the helping process)

```
clc
clear all
close all
data = readmatrix("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.csv") % Pulls .csv for selected time from USGS website
lat = data(:,2);
lon = data(:,3);
mag = sqrt(10.^(abs(data(:,5))));
mag = rescale(mag,0,180);
C = cosd(1:length(lat));
for i = 1:length(mag) % Converts all zeros to nonzeros
    if mag(i) == 0
        mag(i) = 1;
    end
end
A = geoscatter(lat,lon,mag,C,'filled');
geobasemap grayland;
```

As stated above, I am trying to plot the magnitudes correctly because the magnitude data is from the richter scale but the marker sizes in matlab are in points^2. As you can tell I did a quick-fix by rescaling the data from 0 to 180 which make the data appear correct but I don't believe this is the right way to do it.

Comment: `I don't believe this is the right way to do it` - so how would you like to be able to do it? Without a specific desired behaviour, I feel like this question is subjective which is off-topic...

Comment: why rescaling to [0 180]? I understand cannot rescale to negative values, but why upper limit 180?

Comment: @JohnBG 180 is an arbitrary number i decided on that just happened to make the data look pretty good.  I need something like the map function in p5 where: mag = map(mag, 0,10,0,10^10) or something.  Like i said, rescaling was quick fix.

Comment: @Wolfie Well I thought I expressed the desired behavior pretty well, but to reiterate, I would like to take the mag data and change its range from [0,10] to [0,10^10].  In other programming languages, the data would be plotted with an ellipse, the diameter of which is related directly proportional to the magnitude of the earthquake.  So, I suppose you are correct that there is a subjective part to this where the largest datapoint needs to be sized arbitrarily large.  I just need the A vector of marker sizes to appropriately represent the mag data

Comment: Can you just use `interp1` instead of this `map` proposal? Or for some values `x` in the range 0-10 you can just do `x.^10` to scale it?